# Redundant Conformance

Tags: ios, swift, testing

I have the following extension and protocol conformance in my project:

```
//Extension
extension RawRepresentable where Self: Codable {
    // return value as a string
    public var rawValue: String {
        if let json = try? JSONEncoder().encode(self), 
           let string = String(data: json, encoding: .utf8) {
            return string
        } else {
            return "{}"
        }
    }
    
    // parse value from a string
    public init?(rawValue: String) {
 
        if let value = try? JSONDecoder().decode(Self.self, from: Data(rawValue.utf8)) {
            self = value
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

```
//Protocol
extension Optional: RawRepresentable where Wrapped: Codable {}
```

Building the app target(iOS) succeeds but building the test target(unit tests) fails with the error
`Redundant conformance of 'Optional<Wrapped>'  to protocol 'RawRepresentable'`

When I removed the protocol conformance, the app target fails due to an error with this statement:
`@AppStorage(StorageKeys.bag.rawValue) var bag: Bag? = nil`

The error is as follows:

```
Candidate requires that the types 'Bag?' and 'Bool' be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == 'Bool')
Candidate requires that the types 'Bag?' and ‘In’t be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == ‘Int’)
Candidate requires that the types 'Bag?' and ‘Double’ be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == ‘Double’)
Candidate requires that the types 'Bag?' and ‘String’ be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == ‘String’)
Candidate requires that the types 'Bag?' and ‘URL’ be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == ‘URL’)
Candidate requires that the types 'Bag?' and ‘Data’ be equivalent (requirement specified as 'Value' == ‘Data’)
```

I have used the Xcode's `find symbol in workspace` functionality but I can't find that protocol conformance elsewhere. How do I resolve this issue without updating `bag` definition?

Comment: Do you have a [mcve] that reproduces this issue? (That is, a program that includes all the code you've shown, but as little extra code as possible.)

Answer (score 1):

Conforming a type you don't control to a protocol you don't control tends to cause exactly this kind of problem and should be strongly avoided. The most common cause of this kind of problem is that some other thing you import (possibly something provided by Apple) also decided to do the same thing, and now you have a conflicting conformances. A type can only be conformed to a protocol once in the entire system. If you do not control either the type or the protocol, you can't be sure that happens.

Beyond that, your implementation of `extension RawRepresentable where Self: Codable` is simply incorrect. It assumes that every RawRepresentable that is Codable also has a RawValue type of String. This is not true.

You should get rid of both extensions.

What I believe you're trying to do is along the lines of [Store custom data type in @AppStorage with optional initializer?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65587932/store-custom-data-type-in-appstorage-with-optional-initializer) It looks like you've used the "generic" solution. As I noted in the comments there, this is very dangerous for exactly the reason you've run into. See my answer there for a more robust way to solve this problem.